# Display an Image Without Pushing Down Content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am using a template that was purchased to develop a site, and need to insert an image on the page without pushing the content down. Below is the link to the page I am working on:
    http://www.onepropertyway.com/WorkOrder/default.aspx?woid=26&code=8lPRt3hxtg&vid=7

I recently added the following div with the logo:

```
<div style="margin-left:-20px; display:inline; *zoom:1;text-align:center">
<img src="/uploads/logos/8_100h.gif">
</div>`
```

As you can see, the content of the page is being pushed down. I'd like this image to appear in the middle just between the main green menu, and the horizontal line without pushing any content down. I tried using z-index as well, but that did not work either. I am sure this is pretty simple for a seasoned CSSer, but that's not me unfortunately!

Here is a link to the desired look:
[desired look](http://%20%20%20%20http://www.onepropertyway.com/WorkOrder/desired.jpg)

Comment: please provide any screenshot how do you want.?

Comment: See the link I added. http://www.onepropertyway.com/WorkOrder/desired.jpg

Comment: Please decide first you want to image in `img` tag or `background-image` because every time i reloaded page img come either `img` tag or `background-image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this css to `imgContainer`class.

```
.imgContainer {
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: -23px;
}
.row_6 {      
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like for this solution?

Comment: I have already added code please add this css in your code. and i have checked in your page it works perfect.

Comment: Yup, works...do I need the width?...I only ask because the images will be dynamic.

Comment: Yes please give any specific width because whenever if image come in large size so it adjust automatically .

Comment: The height will always be 100px, but the width may change.

Comment: Ok I have updated `.imgContainer` css please update it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the img container:

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="/uploads/logos/8_100h.gif">
</div>
```

Here is the css. This will center the img below the menu and above the horizontal line:

```
.imgContainer {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box; 
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Take the padding off of the h2 "Word Order #26" and header like so. The padding is adding space above the h2 and below the menu. This removes the padding.:

```
header, h2 { //probably better if you make classes for these elements so you can target them
 padding: 0;
}
```

You may want to add a class like this:

```
<header class="headerClass">......</header>

<h2 class="workorder">Work Order #26</h2>

.headerClass {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}


.workorder {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.onepropertyway.com/WorkOrder/default.aspx?woid=26&code=8lPRt3hxtg&vid=7

Comment: I had a typo. the flex properties need to be on the imgContainer class. I updated the answer

Comment: Is this one valid? display: -webkit-flex;

Comment: Yes, it's for safari and older chrome support

Comment: The padding of the h2/header needs to be taken off

Comment: My concern with removing the padding in the style.css is that it will impact the other pages that use that class...

Comment: I added a class "workorder" to h2 so you can target .workorder to take off the padding. Just make sure you don't have any other elements with a class of workorder

Comment: Ugh...still seems to be pushing down

Comment: I updated the answer with classes/html for more specificity. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

use this for image set in center

```css
.container{
position:relative;}
.absolute_logo{
width:200px;
height: 70px;
position:absolute;
left: 0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
top: -27px;
}
.absolute_logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="absolute_logo">
  <img src="/uploads/logos/8_100h.gif" />
</div>
</div>
```